# NullPointerException while using put method of HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, nullpointerexception

The following code is giving me a `NullPointerException`. The problem is on the following line:

```
... 
dataMap.put(nextLine[0], nextLine[6]);
```

What is strange is that I have run this code without the above line and the call to `nextLine[0]` and `nextLine[6]` work exactly as expected - that is they give me back elements of a csv file. I declare and initialise the `HashMap` with the code

```
HashMap<String, String> dataMap = null;
```

earlier in the method

```
  String[] nextLine;
  int counter=0;
  while (counter<40) {
    counter++;

    System.out.println(counter);
    nextLine = reader.readNext(); 
    // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
    System.out.println(nextLine[0] + " - " + nextLine[6] +" - " + "etc...");
    dataMap.put(nextLine[0], nextLine[6]);
  }
  return dataMap;
}
```

Comment: I just wonder about the "24" points for a such trivial newbie coding problem

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, String> dataMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

Your `dataMap` variable isn't initialized at this point.  You should be getting a compiler warning about that.

Comment: Isn't the problem really that it's *explicitly* initialised ? To null ?

Comment: I think Codingscape means to say "is not instantiated"

Comment: Actually, there is a hint here.  He didn't get a warning because he initialized it to null to override the compiler warning he certainly was getting.  You should make it a habit NOT to initialize variables to a "Neutral" value by default, only set them to their real value so the compiler can warn.

Answer (score 5):

Where is datamap initialised ? It's always null.

To clarify, you declare the variable and set it to null. But you need to instantiate a new Map, whether it's a HashMap or similar.

e.g.

```
datamap = new HashMap();
```

(leaving aside generics etc.)

Comment: Yes, it's very strange that dereferencing a pointer that is explicitly null would throw a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

dataMap is declared but not initialized.  It can be initialized with

datamap = new HashMap();

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are three objects accessed on that line.  If nextLine[0] and nextLine[6] aren't null, because the println call above worked, then that leaves dataMap.  Did you do dataMap = new HashMap(); somwehere?

Answer (score 0):

My case was different as Usually, hashmaps throw the null pointer exception when trying to read a key that is not there e.g I have a

`HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

Which is empty or have keys except "someKey", So when I try to

`map.get("someKey") == 0;`

Now this will produce a nullPointerExeption due to matching a null with some integer.

What should I do instead?

Ans: I should instead check for null like

`map.get("someKey") != null;`

Now the runtime error Nullpointer would not raise!

Answer (score -1):

Um, what exactly **do** you expect when you do this?

```
HashMap<String, String> dataMap = null;
...
dataMap.put(...)
```

Comment: I was expecting that null is kind of a place holder, but when you use put the value being "put" make the HashMap no longer equal to null

Comment: If put =null everywhere will my program write itself?

Comment: ...and why a minus point here? I begin to doubt the objectivity of Stackoverflow community.